# Excluding a file while merging in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, merge, tortoisehg

I use Mercurial with TortoiseHg. I have two branches (`A` and `B`) with two files (`toto.cs` and `titi.cs`).

Is there a way, when I want to merge `B` with `A`, to exclude `titi.cs` from merging, and only merge `toto.cs`? If it's possible, how can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure.  Not merging titi.cs is really just using titi.cs exactly as it exists in A or in B (your choice).  You could do that *manually* like this:

```
hg update A
hg merge B
hg revert --rev A titi.cs
```

(swap A and B to go the other direction).
Or you could do that *automatically* in your [Merge Tool Confguration](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration) with something like this in your `.hgrc`.

```
[merge-patterns]
titi.cs = internal:local
```

Which tells Mercurial to always use "this one not that one" for files matching that pattern.

Comment: You should also know that [If the 'other' branch changes the file and 'local' does not, a merge using the internal:local tool will include that change, and vice versa.](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#mergemineortheir)

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about a certain file which you want to be exempt from merging, then see [@Ry4chan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10883348/67988). This is perfectly valid: some files, like build-relating configs, can be autogenerated, and conflict resolution for them is useless. Or, you might actually want to drop changes made in a source file.

If, on the other hand, you are trying to mimic file- or directory-limited merges of SVN-like systems, be careful. The `revert` trick does not mean you merged some files and didn't merge other: you merged everything, the revert was just a kind of merge.

If you want to move some changes from one branch to another (say, backport a fix in a certain subsystem to an old stable branch), you don't merge the files with the fix; instead, you merge the *changesets* containing the fix; [`hg graft`](http://selenic.com/hg/help/graft) will help you do so.