# A practical way to provide code updates via Mercurial without sharing main BitBucket account

Tags: mercurial

I suspect this might be really obvious but I can't find a straightforward solution in the documentation or forums:

I have written some code that is held in a Mercurial repository on BitBucket.

I use this code to build Linux virtual servers. When I build a server, I clone the repo onto the server, run my build script, and then delete the clone. The result is a configured server with several files from my repo located in various folders on the server.

Now, I'm looking for a mechanism where I can roll out bug fixes and improvements to my users' servers after I have handed them over. At that time, I won't have SSH access to the servers and I cannot expect my end users to do anything more complicated than kick off a cron job or launch a script.

To achieve this, I'm thinking of setting up a BitBucket account for my users with read-only access to my repo.

I have no problem writing a script to clone my repo, via this read-only account, and apply the updates, but I don't want to include all my files. In particular, I want to exclude my build script as it is commercially sensitive. I know I could remove it from my repo, but then my build wouldn't work.

Reading around, it seems I may need to create a branch or a fork of my repo (which?). Or maybe a sub-repo? Then, I could remove the sensitive files from that branch/fork/sub-repo and allow my users to clone it via a script.

That's OK, but I need a way to update the branched/forked/sub repo as I make changes to the main one. Can this be automatic? In other words, can it be set up to always reflect the updates made in the main repo? Excluding the sensitive files of course.

I'm not sure I'd want updates to be automatic though, so I'd also like to know how to transfer updates from the main to the branch/fork/sub manually. A merge? If I do a merge, how do I make sure my sensitive files don't get copied across?

To sum up, I have a main repo which contains some sensitive files and I need a way to roll out updates of all but those sensitive files to my read-only users.

Sorry if this is hugely obvious. I'm sure it's a case of not seeing the wood for the trees and being overwhelmed by the possibilities. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are ok with two branches, one for the users clone (main) and other for your main development (dev), the tricky part is merging the new changes from dev to main.

You can solve this by excluding files in the merge process. [Excluding a file while merging in Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879180/excluding-a-file-while-merging-in-mercurial)

By setting the `[merge-patterns]` section in your .hgrc you can sepcify what files are not affected by the merge.

```
[merge-patterns]
build.sh = internal:local
```

For more info read `hg help merge-tools`.

```
"internal:local"
   Uses the local version of files as the merged version.
```

Comment: One thing I'm not sure about is whether I should use clones or branches. I *think* it's clones, especially since I want to protect the dev one from being accessed (even read-only) by my users. Is that right?

Comment: You can download a copy with the bitbucket .zip link, that way the main branch is always downloaded instead of the dev one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you need to solve this in Mercurial at all.
What you actually need is [Continuous Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) / a build server.

The simplest solution goes like this:
Set up a build server with something like [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) or [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/), that's always online and monitors changes in your Bitbucket repository.
You can set it up so that when there's a change in your repository, the build server runs your build script and copies the output to some FTP server, or download site, or whatever.

Now you have a single location that always contains the most recent code changes, but without the sensitive files like the build script.
Then, you can set up a script or cron job that your end users can run to get the newest version of the code from that central location.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to this concept. It's very interesting and could be right for my situation, but I don't see the advantage over Mercurial. I already use Mercurial and BitBucket for version control, so why complicate matters by introducing another system?

Comment: Yes, Mercurial/Bitbucket are for version control. But you are trying to solve a different problem with version control, one that isn't meant to be solved with version control. Automatically compiling your code when it changes and putting it somewhere where your customers can access it... that's exactly what Continuous Integration / build servers are for.

Comment: This looks like a far better aproach. (as long as you are willing to set up a CI server)

Comment: Even if you don't want to set up an actual CI server...you can still do it manually. He already has a build script that compiles everything. It's not much additional work to make the script "publish" the compiled version to a place that the customers can access (FTP, download site...). You just have to remember to execute the script whenever you change something. That's Continuous Integration by hand :-)

Comment: I think I get it now: The main reason to favour a CI / build server over a version control system is that a CI can automatically compile code, thus saving a time-consuming manual task.

Apart from that, it's a case of using the right tool for the job: version control is for version control, not code publishing, which is what CI is for.

Is that about right?

Answer (score 0):

Entire Mercurial trees always get moved around together, so you can't clone or pull just part of a repository (along the file tree axis). You could keep a branch that has only part of the files, and then keep another branch that has everything, making it easy to merge the the partial (in terms of files) branch into the other branch (but merging the other way wouldn't be particularly easy).

I'm thinking maybe [subrepositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository) work for your particular use case.

Comment: In the subrepositories documentation you mentioned, it says:

"Subrepositories is a feature that allows you to treat a collection of repositories as a group. This will allow you to clone, commit to, push, and pull projects and their associated libraries as a group."

That's not what I'm after, so I guess the solution will involve branching or forking.