# Mercurial: TortoiseHg configuration to always prompt for manual resolve for all files when merging

Tags: mercurial, merge, tortoisehg

We use Mercurial via TortoiseHg with the 'workbench'.

When merging branches, we often find the default (auto?) choice of updates is not what we want. We'd like to configure the tool to always prompt for any merge operation.

Each branch has some core files that we need to keep up to date between the two, but also some branch-specific files which need to be preserved.

If we update the core files in one branch we'd like to do a merge to get the latest core files in the other branch. However the default TortoiseHg makes automatic updates that we don't want.

Examples:

1) Branch '1' contains a file '1.xls' and branch '2' has an equivalent '2.xls' which are stored as binary. Merging '1' into a working directory based off '2' causes a delete of '2.xls' and an add of '1.xls'.

2) Branch '1' contains an updated file 'not_core.c' which has an equivalent 'not_core.c' in branch '2'. Merging '1' into a working directory based off '2' causes an unwanted automatic update of 'not-core.c' in '2'.

3) Branch '1' contains updated files 'core1.c' & 'core2.c'. Merging '1' into a working directory based off '2' causes an automatic update of both files, when we'd prefer a prompt to allow us to chose if these core files are updated. Maybe we want just 'core1.c' for now.

I have seen reference to setting 'mergetool.premerge = false' in mercurial.ini, and have tried some variants of this without success.

The ideal setup would be that the graphical manual resolve is triggered for every file that is different.

Can anyone help with a configuration that supports the functionality described?

Thanks, Ian

Answer (score 3):

Three described cases have different nature in you case, you have to use different tricks for different cases

Cases 2 and 3 (non-conflicting changes in files of ranches) *can be* covered (TBT!) by disabling auto-merges in TortoseHG (Main menu - `File` - `Settings` - `Global setting` - `TortoiseHG` - "Auto-resolving merges": False /default - True/)

For case 1 (and other non-content changes - renames, changing attributes) situation is worse and automerge doesn't play: merge mirror history of changes from one branch to another, i.e if in common parent you have only 2.xls, which was deleted|renamed to 1.xls in source branch this change will be reflected in target.

You can try to use different "internal" merge-tool in such merges (when your prefer changes only from one branch - "dummy merge") - internal:local and internal:other. But - they work only for changed content (again!)

Maybe [Keep "My" or "Their" files when doing a merge](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Keep_.22My.22_or_.22Their.22_files_when_doing_a_merge) from TipsandTricks section will help (you can join mentioned merge-revert-resolve into new command in [aliases] and use it instead of ordinary merge, when needed)

Comment: For cases 2 and 3 (non-conflicting changes) I still want to be able to choose which files get updated from the other branch. What I get is automatic 'updates'.
The only workflow I can currently use (within TortoiseHg workbench) is to cancel the merge dialog before the final Commit, then manually revert the unwanted files.

Comment: @user2290652 - if you'll disable automerge, you'll get your preconfigured merge-tool running for every pair of files, which exist in both branches - and will be able to copy into target hunks from any source

Comment: I have 'Auto-resolving merges' set to false, but reading the description of this setting explains why it doesn't help: "...When False all files with changes on both sides of the merge will report as conflicting..."
I need a conflict raising if only the file on the branch I'm merging from has changed, so I can choose whether to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure this using the `merge-patterns` and `merge-tools` sections of `hgrc`.  This set up allowed me to force kdiff3 to be used in my test:

```
[merge-patterns]
** = noautomerge

[merge-tools]
noautomerge.executable = kdiff3
noautomerge.args = $base $local $other -o $output --qall
noautomerge.priority = 1
noautomerge.premerge = False
```

This will turn off the automatic pre-merge that Mercurial does and start up kdiff3 instead.

It will do it for all files but it you might be better to amend the `merge-patterns` section to be a little more specific if that is possible.

Also, be aware of the possibility that your merge tool might automatically resolve the merge itself and if that happens look for command line options to turn that feature off.

Comment: The issue is one of Mercurial automatically updating all files that have changed on the other branch (but are not conflicting). I assumed that was what 'premerge' meant but testing it that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: I hadn't understood that you didn't want ***any*** changes from the other branch without doing a merge. My suggestion prevents auto-merging of files that have changed on both branches (even if the changes are trivial to merge).  I'm not sure if you can configure Mercurial to not take the file changes on the other branch if there's no merge needed (there's no merge needed if you haven't changed it on the local branch - it is effectively an update)

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make that clear enough. Yes, I want to get prompted for _any_ changes from the other branch, so I can choose to ignore them.
The reason for this is that different branches contain files with the same name, but branch-specific content. That may be a poor decision, but it's what has happened historically. We want to preserve
What could work very well is a way to mark files that are ignored during the merge, does this exist? (Not by extension though, only by complete file name).

Comment: OK, I found this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10883348/2290652) to try. Will report back...

Comment: OK, forcing 'internal:xxx' using merge-pattern still doesn't help. I think the underlying problem is that the file changes I want to treat as merges are seen to be updates in Mercurial and will always be applied.
I also did some preliminary tests using 'Git Extensions' and got the same unwanted behaviour. Since I prefer the TortoiseHg workbench UI I didn't explore much further.